# using decimal values in user settings

Tags: c#

I'm having some troubles setting decimal values in the settings file, when it asks me for the type of variable I'm choosing the decimal and the default value is 0.10, this is to imitate 10 cents, but when I run my program and check the value of the variable it's showing as 0.01, this is because I should add an "m" at the end and that's not allowed in the settings file. is there some work-around for this?

also the user may set his/her own price that's entered in to a textbox, this for example could be 0.30 (30 cents) how can i convert the textbox value to 0.30m?

using a double is not an option, I don't want to end up with something like $2.99999999 decimal type is perfect if only I could use it in the settings file like I can hard-coded.

Thanks for replies.

```
public void beginUser(int tblSize)
    {

        decimal tblPrice = 0.00m;
        int minCount = 0;
        decimal curCost = 0.00m;
        string timeStarted = string.Format("{0:HH:mm:ss tt}", DateTime.Now);

        //Setup table price
        switch (tblSize)
        {
            case 0:
                tblPrice = Properties.Settings.Default.tblSmallPrice;
                //tblPrice = 0.10m //this works
                break;
            case 1:
                tblPrice = Properties.Settings.Default.tblBigPrice;
                //tblPrice = 0.15m // this works
                break;
            default:
                tblPrice = 0.10m;
                break;
        }

        //Check how tblPrice appears.
        MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(tblPrice));

        try
        {
            while (true)
            {

                Thread.Sleep(100);
                curCost += tblPrice;
                minCount += 1;
                if (minCount == 60) { Thread.CurrentThread.Abort(); }
            }
        }
        catch (ThreadAbortException)
        {
            TimeSpan span = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(minCount);

            string output = String.Format("Cost: €{0}\r\ncurCost: {1} hour(s) {2} minutes\r\nStarted: {3}", curCost, span.Hours, span.Minutes, timeStarted);
            MessageBox.Show(output);
        }


}
```

Comment: How are you displaying the value, and are you sure the default is really 0.1 rather than 0.01? To parse user-entered text, use `decimal.TryParse`. Note that the `m` suffix is only relevant for C# source code - it's just a suffix to indicate the type of a literal.

Comment: @Jon Skeet , my program uses a while loop to keep track of how many minutes the user has been playing, the price per minute is 0.10cents, if i hard code the value 0.10m I get the correct price of $6.00 in 1 hour, if I set the 0.10 in the settings file I get the price of $0.60

Comment: How are you putting it in the settings file though? I would expect it to work fine.

Comment: I'm manually putting it in the setting file, var type = decimal, value = 0.10.

Comment: if the settings file would allow me to use the M suffix everything would be fine. to try it yourself, type: decimal cost = 0.10; you will get a warning to try adding the M suffix, now add M and it's all good.

Comment: I think the issue has to do with how you are parsing the "settings" file.  It's not clear at all what type of code you are using to parse this file.  You should give a clear codeblock example of the file and the code used to read it.

Comment: @user2864613: As I said in my comment: "Note that the m suffix is only relevant for C# source code - it's just a suffix to indicate the type of a literal." A settings file is not C# source code. Again, show us the code you're using.

Comment: Are you saying you're having issues when setting the applicationSettings / userSettings through the Visual Studio IDE, or is the settings file code you maintain on your own?

Comment: will edit my question to include the code

Comment: @Scott Mermelstein through the IDE application/settings.

Comment: what's the locale of your system?

Comment: I can't even set a double to 0.10 in the application /settings. it shows as 0.01 however I can set 0.15 .. it's seems I am totally screwed

Comment: @user2864613 - Can you add the XML form of your settings file?  Just open it in notepad if you need to.

Answer (score 1):

Use commas! It should work:
0.1 becomes 0,1.

Here you can see how I managed to insert it:

[image]